# Is it really so cold in Albuquerque?

Tags: breaking-bad, realism

While watching the series I was wondering if it's really so cold in New Mexico that all the main characters almost all the time wear long sleeves. I checked the [climate data for Albuquerque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albuquerque,_New_Mexico#Climate) and it seems that there are 8 warm/hot months and 4 colder ones. However, in the series we hardly see anyone wearing short sleeves. Was it intentionally applied by the series creators?

Comment: My folks live in the sub-tropics. They wear jumpers if the temperature drops below 20°C. It's simply acclimatisation. Albuquerque mean daytime temp is 20 or below for 7 months of the year.

Comment: *"Albuquerque has a cold semi-arid climate"*

Comment: Just because it's sunny doesn't mean it's warm.

Comment: You cannot make any conclusions whether it is cold or not based on long/short sleeves. Short sleeves MIGHT indicate that it's warm but long sleeves do not mean that it is cold.

Comment: OR they have 4 very hot months and 8 cold months. They have in "Daily mean" only 4 month that are above 20°C and heavy temp swing between day and night (as seen on max and min difference).

Comment: Based on the daily mean, I would wear long sleeves outside 8-9 months of the year as a matter of course, and occasionally even in the warmer months.  The evening temperatures are not that warm, even in the hottest months.  It may look sunny, but it is at 1 mile elevation.

Comment: Its currently, as I type this, 54 F in Albuquerque right now according to forecast.io.  Definitely jacket weather.

Answer (score 7):

Desert areas are known to be hot in the daytime but cool at night.  From November to March it can definitely be chilly enough at mid day to wear a long sleeve or jacket.  From May to September you'd probably be too warm to wear long sleeves during the day, but not at night.  Albuquerque is also a low pressure point, which means it get some of that Canadian air that comes down through Colorado, plus there's that famous "dry heat" to consider.  Without the humidity, 90 degrees doesn't feel like 90 degrees, it feels cooler than that.